# How can I use .live() with custom function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tabs and get the content of every tab with Ajax
so I had to use .live() function some times !

some thing like this works fine :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
 $('a.bAddItem').live('click',function(){

    $.blockUI({
        centerY: false,
        message: $('#board_addItem'),
        css: { top: '25px', cursor:'default', border:'none', width:'650px' }
    });

  });
});
```

but now I want to use Autosave plugin form :
http://raymond.raw.no/jquery-autosave/

here is the code :

**JS :**

```
$(function(){
    $("form select,form input,form textarea").autosave({
        grouped:true,
        success:function(data) {
            $("#demodebug").html('');
            if ("name" in data)
                $("<span>Select:"+data.name+"</span><br/>").appendTo($("#demodebug"));
            if ("text" in data)
                $("<span>Input:"+data.text+"</span><br/>").appendTo($("#demodebug"));
            if ("textarea" in data)
                $("<span>Textarea:"+data.textarea+"</span><br/>").appendTo($("#demodebug"));
            if ("checkbox" in data)
                $("<span>Checkbox: "+data.checkbox+"</span><br/>").appendTo($("#demodebug"));
            if ("radio" in data)
                $("<span>Radio: "+data.radio+"</span><br/>").appendTo($("#demodebug"));
        }
    });
});
```

the code works fine in the home page , but insdie tabs ( that come from ajax ) does not work ..

the question is :

How can I use .live() or .livequery() with this code ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can bind function to `ajaxSuccess` event, so it will trigger when tabs are loaded. Or trigger custom event and bind `live` to it, like with `click`.

Comment: umm ,, thanks for your replay ,  but how can I do that ? can you show me a sample example please ?  thanks